# Why is it generating newer files instead of moving the duplicates properly?

Tags: c#, file, create-directory

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FileStream outputFileStream = new FileStream("log.txt", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(outputFileStream);

    // writing block

    string originalPathFile = @"C:\Users\user\Downloads\CaptchaCollection\Small\";
    string duplicatePath = @"C:\Users\user\Downloads\CaptchaCollection\Small\Duplicates\";
    string movedOriginal = @"C:\Users\user\Downloads\CaptchaCollection\Small\Sorted\";

    var files = Directory.GetFiles(originalPathFile)
                            .Select(nameWithExtension => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(nameWithExtension))
                            .Where(name => { int number; return int.TryParse(name, out number); })
                            .Select(name => int.Parse(name))
                            .OrderBy(number => number).ToArray();

    while (files.Length > 1)
    {
        string duplicateOfFolder = Directory.CreateDirectory(duplicatePath + files[0].ToString()).FullName;

        for (int j = 1; j < files.Length; j++)
        {
            Bitmap im1 = new Bitmap(originalPathFile + files[0].ToString() + ".png");
            Bitmap im2 = new Bitmap(originalPathFile + files[j].ToString() + ".png");

            if (compare(im1, im2))
            {
                File.Move(originalPathFile + files[j].ToString() + ".png", duplicateOfFolder + files[j].ToString() + ".png");
                writer.WriteLine(files[j].ToString() + ".png" + " is a duplicate of " + files[0].ToString() + ".png \n");
            }
        }

        File.Move(originalPathFile + files[0].ToString() + ".png", movedOriginal + files[0].ToString() + ".png");
        writer.WriteLine(files[0].ToString() + ".png " + "has had its duplicates removed.");

        files = Directory.GetFiles(originalPathFile)
                            .Select(nameWithExtension => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(nameWithExtension))
                            .Where(name => { int number; return int.TryParse(name, out number); })
                            .Select(name => int.Parse(name))
                            .OrderBy(number => number).ToArray();
    }

    writer.Close();
    outputFileStream.Close();
}
```

So this button basically moves duplicate files of an image visually. I got this code from one of my previous questions I've asked. Now I want to use a new folder to place duplicates of a specific image.

For example:
1.png has 5 visual duplicates (65.png,87.png,100.png,103.png,156.png). I want to move all the duplicates to this directory instead of just placing it in the `Duplicates` directory: `C:\Users\user\Downloads\CaptchaCollection\Small\Duplicates\1\`

Now instead what's happening is that it apparently is renaming and regenerating some images. I can't really describe this in words because I can't really see what's going on. What's not happening is that those files are not being moved to the directory of a duplicated file organization.

Folders will create but instead it's not placing it in the proper folder.

Comment: you want to copy 5 files with the SAME name of "1.png" to the SAME directory? Is that what you are saying?

Comment: @TMcKeown Yes that's right. Well they're visually duplicated with different names.

Comment: i don't understand your answer.  You know that every file in a directory must have a unique name right?

Comment: @TMcKeown What do you mean? The name changes as I check every original file. So if I move on to `2.png` and find 3 duplicates, it will move and make a new folder called `2`. So basically what it does is that it uses the outer loop to make files based off of the "original" image name

Comment: If you move on to `2.png` and find 3 duplicates, and create a new folder called `2`, you still can't put 3 files named `2.png` in that folder. What specifically do you want to do with those 3 duplicate files?

Comment: @KenWhite They're visually duplicated. They have different names. ie the names could be (9.png,12.png,21.png)

Comment: Sorry. @TMcKeown asked you "you want to copy 5 files with the same name to the same directory", to which you responded "Yes that's right". TMcKeown then asked "You know that every file in a directory must have a unique name?", to which you replied "What do you mean?" and refered to a "new folder called 2".

Comment: @KenWhite I didn't want to copy them. I have a folder that contains images named *n*.png where n is a number in order. Now visually some of them are duplicated so I want to pro grammatically place all the duplicated files into a new directory that associates with the original file name.

Comment: :-) Make up your mind. TMcKeown asked "You want to copy", to which you responded "Yes that's right". Now it's "I didn't want to copy them". Can you understand the confusion?

Comment: @KenWhite Not copy. I meant move any duplicated file names (not by copying). Ugh how do I say this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your requirement correctly then I think issue is in following lines.

```
if (compare(im1, im2))
{
    File.Move(originalPathFile + files[j].ToString() + ".png", duplicateOfFolder + files[j].ToString() + ".png");
    writer.WriteLine(files[j].ToString() + ".png" + " is a duplicate of " + files[0].ToString() + ".png \n");
}
```

You are actually comparing first file with others but still copying the files in duplicate folder.

Replace following line

```
File.Move(originalPathFile + files[j].ToString() + ".png", duplicateOfFolder + files[j].ToString() + ".png");
```

with

```
String path = duplicateOfFolder;
if (!Directory.Exists(path)) 
{
   Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
}

File.Move(originalPathFile + files[j].ToString() + ".png", path + "\\" + files[j].ToString() + ".png");
```

This should work.

Comment: I'm supposed to move the duplicated files of the original file to a new folder created not the original file.

Comment: Just checked the edit but the directory is not found :(

Comment: I have edited my answer.You forgot to create subfolder with the name of original file name in duplicates folder. That should be causing the issue. You should create the directory before moving the file.

Comment: I added code to create directory as well and modified the answer.

Comment: I've tried it out now but the problem I'm getting is that the folder name seems to be a little buggy and naming the file twice. For example: Folder `690` is named `690690` and folder `1754` is named `17541754`. I've noticed this pattern on almost every folder I saw.

Comment: You need to check in the debugger, what are the filenames stored in the array which you got from linq query. otherwise code I have suggested seems ok.

Comment: Yup gotcha. :) Thanks for your help overall.